# Как содержимое файла добавить в переменные

Tags: python

```
v = open(u"/storage/emulated/0/PyTycoon/Variables.txt","r")
money = v.readline()
s1 = v.readline()
s2 = v.readline()
s3 = v.readline()
L = v.readline()
```

Вот что находится в файле:

```
0
6
1000
10000
1
```

Я не понимаю как сделать чтобы программа корректно читала файл и записывала данные в переменные.

Потратил много часов на попытки, обдумывание, поиск в интернете. Не нашел решения. У меня уже кипит голова, помогите, прошу.

Comment: Когда увидел ваш код захотелось перекрестится. Он абсолютно не читабелен. Вы плохо искали, так или иначе я не понимаю в чём ваша проблема?

Comment: @DaVa я новичок как никак

Comment: Можно так: `s1 = int(v.readline())` Но вообще у вас логика в коде отсутствует, разберитесь сначала с ней, а потом к файлам переходите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно так:

```
with open('num.txt', 'r') as v:   #автоматически открывает и закрывает файл, как по мне более удобная вещь, чем в ручную все делать
    a = v.read().split('\n')

money = int(a[0])
s1 = int(a[1])
s2 = int(a[2])
s3 = int(a[3])
L = int(a[4])
```

Текстовый файл представляет из себя массив строк, и мы указываем на них. А раз там находятся цифры, то мы преобразуем их из строки в число.

В коде так то есть недочеты, а именно передача данных в массив. Должно выглядеть так, раз хотите взять переменную из файла:

```
def shops(k, s1):
    k = s1 * 2
    return k
```

И ставить его лучше в самое начало кода

Answer (score 3):

```
with file = open('data.txt') as file:
    s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 =  map(int, file.readlines())
```

Answer (score 1):

Как уже предложили в комментариях

```
    file = open('data.txt', 'r+')
    
    s1 = int(file.readline())
    s2 = int(file.readline())
    s3 = int(file.readline())
    s4 = int(file.readline())
    s5 = int(file.readline())
    
    print(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)
```